# js.erb weird error when retrieving date

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a calendar setup where dates are displayed along a carousel and tasks can be assigned to each day. I have setup a nice jquery dialog box for entering the task and I am now trying to create an ajax response. Upon submitting it should send my data to the server and update the page via a `create.js.erb` page. In order to do this I must extract the date from my @log_entry variable and use jquery to update and add that entry to the carousel entry for that specified date. For some reason, however, I cannot seem to extract the date from my `@log_entry` variable used to save to the database. When I do a simple test like `alert(<%=  @log_entry.date %>);` it returns a weird number that Im asuming represents a year, 1978 which seems to decrease by one for every day I move forward on the carousel. Here is the code in question:

Controller:

```
def create
  @athlete = current_user
  @log_entry = @athlete.log_entries.create(params[:log_entry]) 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to log_entries_path }
    format.js
  end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
alert(<%=  @log_entry.date %>);
```

I have no clue as to why it would alert somthing like 1978, where could it possibly get that number? In the console after I save it and enter `LogEntry.last.date.to_s` I get "2012-01-03". Watching the server everything seems to make sense as well. This seems to be the only attribute that doesn't display properly because when I put this instead: `alert(<%=  @log_entry.id %>);` I get the correct id for that entry. If it helps at all I noticed up intill Dec 31st the year decreases by one untill finally reaching 1968 but then when I change to Jan 1st it jumps to 2010 and then continues to decrease by one each day.

Any Ideas? I am using rails 3.0.0

Just some further info if it helps the server log for saving an entry:

```
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Save", "log_entry"=>{"workouts_attributes"=>{"0"=>
{"time_of_day"=>"AM", "summary"=>"d", "workout_times_attributes"=>{"0"=>
{"duration"=>"0:00", "zone"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}}, "date"=>"Wed Dec 28 00:00:00
 -0700 2011"}, "authenticity_token"=>"yKFf4cWujAaNITVthwX9Y7StXJc9eVjdT2v8DStD1C8=",
 "utf8"=>"\342\234\223"}
  Athlete Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."type" = 'Athlete') 
AND ("users"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "log_entries" ("athlete_id", "created_at", "date", "feel", 
"updated_at") VALUES (1, '2011-12-29 03:22:36.337600', '2011-12-28', NULL, '2011-12-29 
03:22:36.337600')
```

Thanks,
G

Comment: Curious to whether or not it would format correctly if you alert `date.to_s` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the alert function is confused about how to render the date properly.  Try first passing it into a JavaScript Date object:

```
var date = new Date(<%=  @log_entry.date %>);
alert(date);
```

Comment: Okay this seems to solve part of the problem! I now get a response: Wed Dec 31 1969 17:00:02 GMT-0700 (MST) Any idea as to why it still would be 1969 instead of 2011?

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but I'd make sure your 'date' field is of the same type as your updated_at/created_at fields (I believe they are set to 'datetime').

Comment: Thanks @johnernaut I actually just pass the date object through a hidden field in the form. This date is taken from the url in the format `new/2012-01-03` and then passed to the @date object with `Date.parse(params[:date])` I tried switching it to `DateTime.parse(...` but I still get the same result.